# RTB SelectAll only working on last item in StackPanel

Tags: c#, wpf, richtextbox, caret

So either I am missing something stupidly simple or this is the weirdest bug I've encountered in a long time.

This is my application:

[image: Basic Screen Layout]

The user can add a New TestStep by clicking the 'Add Step' button in the lower left. Each TestStep (in this case three) are their own self-contained UserControls that are added to a transparent stackpanel. Double clicking on a step will allow the user to edit like this:

[image: Basic Selection]

So far so good! This is where it gets weird, if I select any step other than the last step at the bottom of the panel (#3 in this case) I get this:

[image]

Everything works *except* the `SelectAll()` functionality.

The little arrow to the left of the 'Add Step' button allows the user to adjust the order of the TestSteps by moving the selected step up one. When reordering, I remove the selected step and then do an insert one index above which effectively makes it "swap places" with the TestStep above it.  The reason I point this out is because the `SelectAll()` problem remains the same. The bottom most one works, all others do not, regardless of which control was added last.

Below is the code that is triggered by the `MouseUp` event on the UserControl:

```
contentBox.IsHitTestVisible = true;
contentBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(240, 240, 240));
contentBox.IsReadOnly = false;
contentBox.Focus();
contentBox.SelectAll();
```

This code exists within each UserControl so the `contentBox` references the RichTextBox for that particular instance. Note that the `HitTest`, `Background`, and `IsReadOnly` properties work all the time for every step. Previously I was using the following code to set the caret to the end of the text:

```
contentBox.IsHitTestVisible = true;
contentBox.Background = new SolidColorBrush(Color.FromRgb(240, 240, 240));
contentBox.IsReadOnly = false;
//manage caret position
TextPointer newPointer = contentBox.CaretPosition;
newPointer = newPointer.DocumentEnd;
contentBox.CaretPosition = newPointer;
contentBox.Focus();
Keyboard.Focus(contentBox);
```

With this code block, everything worked as well showing that the problem isn't related to correctly focusing the `contentBox`.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated! At this point I have run out of ideas.

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

Here is the XAML for the StackPanel:

```
    <ScrollViewer Grid.Column="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0,5,5,0" Grid.Row="1" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" >
                <StackPanel x:Name="stepPanel" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="White" />
    </ScrollViewer>
```

and here is the XAML for the user control:

```
<UserControl x:Name="mainStepControl" x:Class="Test_Script_Writer_2._1.testStep"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             mc:Ignorable="d" 
             MouseEnter="mainStepControl_MouseEnter"
             MouseLeave="mainStepControl_MouseLeave"
             MouseUp="mainStepControl_MouseUp"

             d:DesignHeight="150" d:DesignWidth="400" Background="White">
    <Border x:Name="mainStepBorder" BorderBrush="#FFD9C5B4" BorderThickness="3" CornerRadius="6" Margin="3" Padding="3" Background="#8DA3BD">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="17*"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="1.5*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <RichTextBox x:Name="contentBox" 
                         Background="Transparent" 
                         BorderThickness="0" 
                         Margin="0,0,0,0" 
                         Grid.Column="1" 
                         Grid.RowSpan="2" 
                         IsReadOnly="False"
                         IsHitTestVisible="False"
                         BorderBrush="{x:Null}" 
                         SelectionBrush="#FF3399FF">
                <FlowDocument>
                    <Paragraph/>
                </FlowDocument>
            </RichTextBox>
            <Label x:Name="indexLabel" Content="Test" VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Margin="0" FontSize="16" FontWeight="Bold" FontFamily="MV Boli" Foreground="#FF070FBB"/>
            <Button Grid.Column="2" Style="{StaticResource {x:Static ToolBar.ButtonStyleKey}}" HorizontalAlignment="Right" VerticalAlignment="Center" Width="25" FontWeight="Bold" BorderBrush="{x:Null}" Foreground="Red" Height="25" Click="Button_Click" Margin="0,0,3,0" >
                <Button.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="Resources/delete (1).png" Stretch="Uniform"/>
                </Button.Background>

            </Button>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</UserControl>
```

Comment: Are you using any styles for RTB? Show the XAML or Code for RTB and stackpanel

Comment: @Ganesh Please see updated question for XAML.  I'm not using any styles that I am aware of.  Plus even if something like that were the case, wouldn't that affect all the instances equally?

Comment: could you upload your demo?

Comment: @Neil I did a simple publish and put the files in Dropbox: https://www.dropbox.com/sh/fgunifl9tmlr1w5/AAAGDP5UXAbkW1JS_7ThWSiCa?dl=0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I ended up finding the problem line.  I had a `Keyboard.ClearFocus();` line of code that I used to clear the selection of all other unselected steps.  This ensured that if you select step 1 and then click to highlight step 2, step 1 won't still have a caret blinking or a text selected.  Unfortunately based on the way i was doing my loop it didn't constrain this line to the instance of the object and bubbled up to the entire application.

So in the case with three steps where step 2 is supposed to be selected, it would unselect step 1, select step 2, and unselect step 3 which would also unfortunately unselect step 2 as well instead of staying within it's instance.

Answer (score 0):

Hope this help:

```
 RichTextBox.Loaded += delegate
        {
            Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(
                DispatcherPriority.Normal,
                new Action(
                    delegate()
                    {
                        Keyboard.Focus(RichTextBox);
                        RichTextBox.Selection.Select(
                            RichTextBox.Document.ContentStart,
                            RichTextBox.Document.ContentEnd);
                    }));
        };
```

Comment: No dice, same problem.